# How to split a string on pattern of one or more repeating character and retain match?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

For example, get a string `abaacaaa`, a character `a`, split the string to get `['ab', 'aac', 'aaa']`.

```
string = 'abaacaaa'
string.split('a')      // 1. ["", "b", "", "c", "", "", ""]
string.split(/(?=a)/)  // 2. ["ab", "a", "ac", "a", "a", "a"]
string.split(/(?=a+)/) // 3. ["ab", "a", "ac", "a", "a", "a"]

string.split(/*???*/)  // 4. ['ab', 'aac', 'aaa']
```

Why is **3rd** expression outputs the same value as **2nd** even if `+` presented after a, and what to put into **4th**?

---

**Edit:**

`string.match(/a+[^a]*/g)` doesn't work properly in `babaacaaa`.

```
string = 'babaacaaa'     // should be splited to ['b', 'ab', 'aac', 'aaa']
string.match(/a+[^a]*/g) // ["ab", "aac", "aaa"]
```

Comment: By what context you expect the string to get splitted?

Comment: I want to rotate a string to be minimum laxicographically. E.g From `abaca` to `aabac`

Comment: Unanchored lookaheads test each position in the input string. Hence, 2 = 3. Also, `'abaacaaa'.match(/a+[^a]*/g)` seems to work as 4).

Comment: In python you could also use lookbehinds to find the position you asked for to perform a split operation (e.g. `^|(?<=[^a])(?=a+(?:[^a]|$))` but unfortunately lookbehinds are not supported by javascript at the moment. Check: https://regex101.com/r/qDrobh/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solutions 2 and 3 are equal because unanchored lookaheads test each position in the input.  string. `(?=a)` tests the start of string in `abaacaaa`, and finds a match, the leading empty result is discarded. Next, it tries after `a`, no match since the char to the right is `b`, the regex engine goes on to the next position. Next, it matches after `b`. `ab` is added to the result. Then it matches a position after `a`, adds `a` to the resulting array, and goes to the next position to find a match. And so on. With `(?=a+)` the process is indetical, it just matches 1+ `a`s, but still tests each position.

To split `babaacaaa`, you need

```js
var s = 'babaacaaa';
console.log(
  s.split(/(a+[^a]*)/).filter(Boolean)
);
```

The `a+[^a]*` matches

- `a+` - 1 or more `a`
- `[^a]*` - 0 or more chars other than `a`

The capturing group allows adding matched substrings to the resulting `split` array, and `.filter(Boolean)` will discard empty matches in between adjoining matches.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let string = 'abaacaaa'
let result = string.match(/a*([^a]+|a)/g)
console.log(result)

string = 'babaacaaa'
result = string.match(/a*([^a]+|a)/g)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

`string.match(/^[^a]+|a+[^a]*/g)` seems to work as expected.